# Map through an array to receive multiple get request back

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have this array of Parameters (silly example):

```
const params = ["dididid", "djdjdjdjd","djdjddjdj]
```

Now I would like to map through it to receive multiple response from this get request:

```
{params && params.map(param=>{
                return (
                       axios.get(`http://${REACT_APP_HOSTNAME}:${REACT_APP_PORT}/api/pageThumbnail/${docProps.id}/${param}`).then(
                        function (response){
                            
                          
                             setResponse(response.data)
                          
                      
                        }
                   )
                )
                    
            })}
```

Basically I would like to receive back an array of response.data according to the params I map through. But trying this, when I go se the state I will see only one response sent back. What Shall I do? Thank you

Comment: Promise is your friend here

Comment: I'm a newbie on async/await and axios, Would you help me understand better?

Comment: as suggested, please use promises, added code in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it can be done either with traditional Promise approach or just by using axios.all;

```
axios.all([requestOne, requestTwo, requestThree]).then(axios.spread((...responses) => {

  const responseOne = responses[0]

  const responseTwo = responses[1]

  const responesThree = responses[2]

  // use/access the results 

})).catch(errors => {

  // react on errors.

})
```

with promise;

```
let URL1 = "https://www.something.com"
let URL2 = "https://www.something1.com"
let URL3 = "https://www.something2.com"

const promise1 = axios.get(URL1);
const promise2 = axios.get(URL2);
const promise3 = axios.get(URL3);

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use promise, Async/await can help.

```
{params && params.map(async (param)=>{
                return (
                       await axios.get(`http://${REACT_APP_HOSTNAME}:${REACT_APP_PORT}/api/pageThumbnail/${docProps.id}/${param}`).then(
                        function (response){
                            
                          
                             setResponse(response.data)
                          
                      
                        }
                   )
                )
                    
            })}
```